# Create ActiveX Control and set Value in same Sub

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I am programatically creating an Excel Workbook in which I need to create some ScrollBars on first opening of the workbook, using VBA.

I also need to set the value of the ScrollBars at the same time.

Here is some sample code:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Call Add_Scroll
    Call Set_Scroll
End Sub

Sub Add_Scroll()
    Sheets("Sheet1").OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.ScrollBar.1", Link:=False, _
        DisplayAsIcon:=False, Left:=159.75, Top:=77.25, Width:=290.25, Height _
        :=36.75).Name = "Scroll_1"
End Sub

Sub Set_Scroll()
    Sheets("Sheet1").Scroll_1.Value = 32767
End Sub

Sub Add_Set_Scroll()
    Sheets("Sheet1").OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.ScrollBar.1", Link:=False, _
        DisplayAsIcon:=False, Left:=159.75, Top:=77.25, Width:=290.25, Height _
        :=36.75).Name = "Scroll_1"
    Sheets("Sheet1").Scroll_1.Value = 32767
End Sub
```

Now, if I run `Add_Scroll` and then `Set_Scroll` manually, I get a ScrollBar created and then its value set.

But upon opening the workbook, or running `Add_Set_Scroll` I get:

[image: Run-time Error 438, Object doesn't support this propperty or method]

Unless I comment out the call to `Set_Scroll`

It's almost like the code is running too quickly for the underlying processes and tries to set the value of the scrollbar before it's been properly created.

I've tried adding in an arbitrary delay, or making `Add_Scroll` a function and evaluating the return (i.e., ensuring it waits) before calling `Set_Scroll`, all to no avail.

Searching has yielded nothing helpful, I would be very grateful if anyone can shed any light on this

Comment: When does `Add_Set_Scroll()` get called? Which line does the error occur on when you run this Sub? The reference to `Sheets("Sheet1").Scroll_1.Value = 32767` seems wrong to me, but you say it does work when you manually execute `Set_Scroll()`...

Comment: @FreeMan, `Add_Set_Scroll` does not get called, unless I manually run it. This is just example code to demonstrate that setting the value of the control gives an error if it happens immediately after creation of the control, whether in the same Sub or in individual subs called consecutively from another Sub. The error occurs on the line where the Scroll value is set.

Comment: @FreeMan. Thanks, your comment set me looking in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try. It references the object properly, and also has a retry:

```
Sub Add_Set_Scroll()
Dim RetryCount as integer

  On Error Goto eh
  RetryCount = 0
  Sheets("Sheet1").OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.ScrollBar.1", Link:=False, _
    DisplayAsIcon:=False, Left:=159.75, Top:=77.25, Width:=290.25, Height _
    :=36.75).Name = "Scroll_1"
  Sheets("Sheet1").OLEObjects("Scroll_1").object.Value = 32767

  exit sub

eh:
  If retrycount < 5 then
    RetryCount = RetryCount  + 1
    Resume
  else
    MsgBox "Tried 5 times, can't get to the scroll bar"
    Resume Next
  End if
End Sub
```

You can, of course, change the number of retrys to find an appropriate value, and change/eliminate the failed handling. You may need to put something very different in there instead of `MsgBox` if you can't get access to your scroll bar object.

Comment: Thanks very much for a useful working example of `On Error Resume Next`, as well.

Answer (score 0):

Freeman's comment above set me on the right track, so thanks...
The problem was in the way I was setting the value:

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Scroll_1.Value = 32767
```

Should be:

```
Sheets("Sheet1").OLEObjects("Scroll_1").Object.Value = 32767
```

From [Using ActiveX Controls on Sheets [Excel 2003 VBA Language Reference]](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa221581(v=office.11).aspx)

I guess that when the control is created, then it is registered as an OLEObject immediately, but it must take some time for it to be registered explicitly as a property of the worksheet as well, hence the reason the first example works if I run them separately.

Comment: Glad I could help. Guess I should have made it an answer :/.  Since it seems to be a simple timing issue, I would think you could try an `On Error Resume` wrapper around the `.Object.value` portion. I would test it in a small, sample project that won't matter if forcing a shut down destroys. You may also include a counter so that if retrys up to, say 5 times, to avoid an infinite loop.

Comment: If you want to make it an answer, I'll accept it. I'll try the wrapper thing as well thanks. I'm very new to VBA, and had thought about that but was unsure how to do it. Now, Python, on the other hand...